# Is there a way to auto assign tickets based on the requestor On SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am wondering if it is possible at all to automate the assigning of tickets in SharePoint.  I understand this might be difficult to build but implementing this would essentially make the entire process automated, from when a ticket hits our queue, to the assigning part, to the notification that's sent to the agent that is assigned the ticket.

I have no idea how to go about it but I would need to take into accountability which agent work with certain groups of requestors. Ideally, there are a group of requestors that are assigned to every agent, and it would assign tickets automatically - in other words every agent will receive tickets for requestors they are responsible for.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAR92.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCxiH.png)

I tried creating a new flow by using Power Automate.  In the image above, the flow starts when a new item is created for the SharePoint site.  The condition is if any of the Display names equals any of those, which is why I chose OR at the top of the condition.  then if Yes, send an email to the assigned agent..

This flow allows for the assigned agent to be sent a generic email for the new ticket, but it doesn't auto assign the ticket to them in the help desk sharepoint site.

Comment: It will not auto-update the SharePoint list item when you send an email to agent. You will have to update the SharePoint list item with agent name using **Update item** action in Power automate flows.